# Filter from 3 characters ng-table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I need my filter start to filter from 3 characters. I'm using ng-table. Thank's.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXRn8.png)

It is the standard filter component

```
<td data-title="'Vigência'" filter="{ 'Ano': 'number'}" sortable="'Ano'">
                    {{data.year}}
                </td>
```

Comment: Can we see your filter code?  Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can do something using *filterDelay*, check it: https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/wiki/Configuring-your-table-with-ngTableParams#user-content-filterdelay